# Webブラウザ負荷テスト時のタイムアウトエラーについてです。

Tags: http, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Webブラウザ負荷テスト時のタイムアウトエラーについてです。

自サイトの負荷テストで複数のWebブラウザ(Google Chrome)を同時に動かし何秒でレスポンスが返ってくるかを計測しています。

複数のWebブラウザを1台のPCで動作させているのですが、タイムアウトエラーとなってしまう可能性が高い(全体のリクエストの37%程度)、また全体的にレスポンスが遅い(通常は1秒もかからないのに平均5秒程度)です。

■質問
何が原因でタイムアウトエラー・速度低下となってしまうのか、その原因を切り分け・特定したいのですが、何か良い方法・ツールはないでしょうか？
また以下の情報から原因予想が立ったら教えて頂けますでしょうか？
どんなささいな情報でも解決に向う可能性があるので、ご教授下さい。

■構成
PC→ルータ(市販の安い物)→ハブ(市販の安い物)→光モデム→マンションVDSL集合装置→インターネット(プロバイダ)→自サイトサーバ

■ポイント
上記構成のどこがボトルネックでタイムアウトになってしまうのか、原因の切り分けがしたいのです。

■動作情報
【1台のPCで10個のブラウザ×20アクセス】これが1セット
1セットが完了したら次のセットへ、というオペレーションを自動で行っています。

■数値情報
またアクセス中のリソースは以下の通りとなります。
CPU : 30～50%
ネットワーク受信 : 10Mbps～45Mbps
※MAX100Mbpsの回線なので単純にネットワークの回線速度が足りていないのでしょうか？

また、夜間にタイムアウト回数と速度低下が特に顕著になる傾向があります。
やはりマンションVDSL集合装置→インターネット(プロバイダ)あたりが原因なのでしょうか？

それともCPUを結構使っているので、単純にPCのCUPスペックが足りていないのでしょうか？

■ツール情報
Selenium WebDriverというテストツールを使用してWebブラウザ(Google Chrome)を自動操作しています。

■環境
Win8.1 Pro
Google Chrome
Selenium WebDriver

Comment: マルチポスト　https://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/10333

Comment: マルチポスト　http://qiita.com/galcam/items/d0e11af68b59640a913e

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/89035

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10178317895

Comment: オフトピかもしれませんが、Selenium WebDriverはフロントの機能的なテストをするツールで、メモリを沢山食いますし、負荷試験の用途では推奨されません。JMeter とかの負荷テスト用のツールを使った方がいいですよ。後、ツールにかかわらず、負荷をかける側のクライアントの性能がネックになることがあります。クライアントを複数使って負荷を分散することも試してみるといいと思います。クラウドを使うなどして、上手く負荷をかけてみてください。

Answer (score 0):

「CPUを使っている」の根拠となる数字がよく分かりませんが、使用率が100%に張り付いていないならCPUにはまだ余裕があります。ディスク・ネットワークなどのIOで待ちがあるはずです。

いろいろな可能性はありますが、お察しの通り「ネットワークの帯域が足りていない」というのはボトルネックの候補の一つと言えます。
[フレッツ網とISPの境界で詰まっている](http://blog.amedama.jp/entry/2017/04/08/181728)ことが顕著になっているようで、夜間の利用者が多い時間帯にその影響が出ているのかもしれません。しかし、お使いのISPが“詰まっている”状況をリアルタイムで公開しているはずもなく、ボトルネックと断言はできません。

お使いのISPの帯域を測ることが目的ではないなら、ISPを経由しない形で、なんなら不確定要素を排除して直接サーバに負荷をかけるようにしてください。
自宅から負荷をかけたときのレスポンスより、「サーバーに負荷がかかるときに何が起きるか」がまずは重要です。その次に、サーバーに負荷がかかっている状態で自宅から閲覧してみるのは手かもしれません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。まずサーバはレスポンスを通常通り直ぐに返しているのでサーバには問題ありません。
ご指摘の通り、ディスク使用率が100%張り付きとなっていました。どのようにしたら原因が分かるでしょうか？

Comment: ディスク使用率が100%の主語は、クライアント側のPCでしょうか。原因も何も「ツールの使い方に対して、PCの性能が足りていない」だけではないでしょうか。

Comment: 別のサイトで「10個のブラウザ x 20アクセスということは、200同時アクセスしているということでしょうか？　メモリ不足で、SWAP しているとかは無いですよね？」という指摘があり、これが真実じゃないですかね。マルチポストしているなら、各投稿それぞれに誠実に情報を追加していってください（頑張ってください）。